# How to get Azure Webapp start/stop events to Azure Functions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have a requirement when webapp is started or stoped my azure function should be called. I have gone through Azure Grid Events, using Subscription as Resource Group but it does not capture any event on WebApp. So Azure Function is not called.
Is it possible to achieve this using Event Grid? I dont want to create use Custom Events.

Comment: You should try application insights paired with availability monitoring alert. You should be able to call your function (if it is an http trigger).

Comment: @Thomas Thank for your help. Is it possible to do this using Azure Event Grid? As Azure Event Grid is for handling Events.

Comment: I don't think so. Tis is why I suggested this option. EventGrid will handle some event but I dont think azure functions send event to eventgrid for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve this using Event Grid? I dont want to create use Custom Events.

In short answer, it is not possbile to do that currenctly. We could get more information about Event grid from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview).

> **Currently, the following Azure services support sending events to Event Grid:**
>
> - Azure Subscriptions (management operations)
> - Custom Topics
> - Event Hubs
> - IoT Hub
> - Resource Groups (management operations)
> - Service Bus
> - Storage Blob
> - Storage General-purpose v2 (GPv2)

**Note:** It supports part of the region currently.

As Thomas mentioned that you could  try to  application insights paired with availability monitoring alert.